# MySQL getting records between specific month, year

Tags: mysql, database, between

I have a table called Accounts which has a date column named TransactionDate. I need to get all the records where TransactionDate is between month,year.

For example, all records where TransactionDate is between 6, 2016 and 8, 2017.

My query string looks like:

```
SELECT Amount 
  FROM Accounts 
 WHERE (MONTH(TransactionDate) BETWEEN 6 and 8) 
   AND (YEAR(TransactionDate) BETWEEN 2016 and 2017)  
 ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC
```

However it only gives me records for June, July 2016 and August 2017. It skips the records for Jan 2017, Spet, Nov 2016.

I am attaching the screenshot of the TransactionDate column of all records (there are 31 of them)

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the returned result

[image]

What is wrong with my query? Also this query is going to be dynamic, i.e. users will choose the month and year from a form and the result will be returned to them.

Thank you.

Comment: That output based on the input you show and the query you run Look Correct

Answer (score 1):

You simply filter the queries by those that are BEFORE 2017-08 and AFTER 2016-06

```
SELECT Amount 
  FROM Accounts 
 WHERE TransactionDate > '2016-06-01T00:00:00' 
   AND TransactionDate < '2017-08-01T00:00:00' 
 ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC
```

what's wrong with your current query is that you're getting data where the month is June, July, or August, AND where the year is 2016 or 2017. This isn't right, you want to filter by the Date itself, not it's components.

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
select a.Amount
from Accounts a
where a.TransactionDate >= '2016-06-01' AND
      a.TransactionDate < '2017-09-01'
order by a.TransactionDate ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you need

```
SELECT Amount , ExpenseType , 
      MONTHNAME(TransactionDate) AS TransactionMonthString
      Year(TransactionDate) AS TransactionYearString
FROM Accounts 
WHERE TransactionDate >= '2016-06-01' AND TransactionDate <= '2017-08-01'   
ORDER BY TransactionDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Amount from Accounts where TransactionDate  BETWEEN '2016-04-02' AND '2017-08-03';
```

try this,good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using date_format function of mysql

```
 SELECT 
     Amount
 FROM
     Accounts
 WHERE
     DATE_FORMAT(TransactionDate, '%Y-%m') BETWEEN '2016-06' AND '2017-08' ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC;
```

This should work perfectly.